# Nested arrays and ID and NAME

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to find the sum of the values of the selected radio buttons.

What I know about naming elements it that you can give the same name for many elements but the id must be unique for each tag.

```
<div class="set">
<div><input name="answers[1]" value="1" type="radio"/></div>
<div><input name="answers[1]" value="2" type="radio"/></div>
<div><input name="answers[1]" value="3" type="radio"/></div>   
<div><input name="answers[1]" value="4" type="radio"/></div>
</div>

<div class="set">
<div><input name="answers[2]" value="5" type="radio"/></div>
<div><input name="answers[2]" value="6" type="radio"/></div>
<div><input name="answers[2]" value="7" type="radio"/></div>   
<div><input name="answers[2]" value="8" type="radio"/></div>
</div>
```

This is my code to find how many input was selected in `answer[1]`

```
//For each radio button if it is checked get the value and break.
var c=0;
   for (var i = 0; i < answer[1].length; i++)
       if (answer[i].checked){
           //radio is selected
           c+=answer[i].value;
           break;
        }
    alert(c);
```

How can I loop in the array?

and what if it was more complected, like finding the sum of the values of the selected radio buttons with jscript if they where in array of DIVs with name of `set`, and the DIVs `set` were in another DIV with id `opt`.

```
<div id="opt">
    <div class="set" name="set[1]">
        <div><input name="answers[1]" value="1" type="radio"/></div>
        <div><input name="answers[1]" value="2" type="radio"/></div>
        <div><input name="answers[1]" value="3" type="radio"/></div>   
        <div><input name="answers[1]" value="4" type="radio"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="set" name="set[2]">
        <div><input name="answers[1]" value="5" type="radio"/></div>
        <div><input name="answers[1]" value="6" type="radio"/></div>
        <div><input name="answers[1]" value="7" type="radio"/></div>   
        <div><input name="answers[1]" value="8" type="radio"/></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is the general rule?

What if I want to solve this with jquery? would this be easier?

Comment: Different approach: Using the same class name for grouped elements make life a bit easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var c=0;
  for (var i = 0; i < answer[1].length; i++)
   if (answer[i].checked){
       //radio is selected
       c+=answer[i].value;
       break;
    }
alert(c);
```

This is your function. This isn't going to work. JavaScript doesn't know to what `answer[1]` refers. HTML elements (few exceptions) aren't directly linked as a JavaScript variable. Also using the keyword `break` in a loop causes the loop to stop entirely.

Using `getElementsByName` works.

```
var answers = document.getElementsByName("answer[1]");
var c=0;
  for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++)
   if (answers[i]checked){
       //radio is selected
       c+=answers[i].value;
    }
alert(c);
```

This will retrieve all elements with the name `answer[1]` and store them in a `HTML collection` called answers. Now we can loop over the collection as if it were an array.

You can also narrow your selection by doing this:

```
document.getElementsByName("set[1]")[0].getElementsByName("answer[1]");
```

This will select all elements with name `set[1]`, select the first element (and only) in the collection: `[0]`, then perform a selection on its childs.